# JS-object-like functions for lua tables

Tags: lua, lua-table

Lua tables are similar to JavaScript objects so it seems natural to have functions similar to which js builtin objects `Object` and `Array`, and `lodash` library provide. Namely: `keys`, `values`, `entries`, `pick`, `omit`, `map`, `reduce`, `find`, `filter`, etc Builtin `table` doesn't have any of this. I know I can code them by myself, but I think somebody had already done this and there should be some libraries on `luarocks`. Can anybody point them out?

Comment: `I can code them by myself` - And you should do this.  `somebody had already done this` - Yes.  You can search on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [Lua Functional Library](https://luafun.github.io/), as it implements most (if not all) of the functions you've listed. It targets LuaJIT, but also supports other Lua versions.

Comment: Thanks. Though it seems stuck in 2017 on alpha-version and Penlight seems to be the one I was thinking about

Comment: Penlight is definitely a good option, although it appears to have more dependencies than LuaFun.